mailnotifier in de.codecentic.boot.admin.server.comfig.adminservernotifierautoconfiguration$mailnotifierconfiguration
Description:
Parameter 1 of method mailNotifier in de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerNotifierAutoConfiguration$MailNotifierConfiguration required a bean of type 'de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.domain.entities.InstanceRepository' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.domain.entities.InstanceRepository' in your configuration.
When using starter-mail in Spring Boot and adding it to application.properties, the following error occurs:
Parameter 1 of method mailNotifier in de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerNotifierAutoConfiguration$MailNotifierConfiguration required a bean of type 'de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.domain.entities.InstanceRepository' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.domain.entities.InstanceRepo
